# What is this transformer-like component, and why is it not really connected?

Tags: power-supply, computers, atx

Recently, a power surge took out a few components in my PC's ATX power supply. While repairing (I hope), one component in the power drew my attention. I'm an electronics engineer, but I'm confused about it's purpose:

[image]

At first sight, it looks like a transformer, but with only one connection (the blue cable). Too intrigued, I cut away the tape, and found that the cable was just hooked to the plastic lip. No winding, no other connections.

To make it even more intriguing, the connector goes to the ATX's supply circuit board, but both contacts are on the same trace (i.e. shorted together), just after the mains fuse.

Does anyone know of a legitimate function for this component? I have not been able to find the part number anywhere.

PS: This is *not* a delayed April 1 prank.

**EDIT**: Thanks for all the replies and comments below! Later, I found another picture on the 'web, showing an even more sophisticated plastic form to hook the wire loop onto: it even had an anti-falloff feature to avoid to loop from freeing itself.

Comment: A weight :D https://regmedia.co.uk/2011/04/11/fake_1.jpg

Comment: With the answer you got, I suppose you no longer want to repair the PSU. Throw it away and get a real one :-)

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. It's still sitting on the workbench. I installed an older -working- supply for the moment. The 'new' one surprisingly  has quite nice connectors, which might be salvable ;-) And a quiet fan!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's supposed to look like a passive PFC choke. Real PFC chokes were common in the early-mid 2000s. Those were replaced by active and lighter counterparts on more recent power supplies.

Worst passive PFC knock-off I heard about from my friends in China was that the customers associated heavy weight with PFC chokes, so the manufacturers put a large stone in each non-PFC power supply and marked it with PFC. Then the customers complained that there was a rattle from the power supply to they "improved" quality by wrapping the stone in newspaper to cushion it.

More examples from the interwebz:
[image: exhibit A]
[image: exhibit B]
[image: exhibit C]

Comment: Supposed to look like? But it is not?

Comment: @EugeneSh. With zero turns, no.

Comment: So it *is* a weight, as commented :)

Comment: hey, just google "fake pfc transformer". Looks similar.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, and one of the "better" I've seen. What's the USB gizmo?

Comment: a fake SSD drive out of usb stick :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Neat! Did it work?

Comment: Dunno, not mine, fortunately :) But I heard they manage to reformat the sticks so they report a fake size when plugged in (not working, of course)

Comment: LOL WOW... juts googled... pretty common practice I see.. And most seem to be stamped PFCxxxx as the part number on top just to give the inspector the nod.

Comment: That middle one with the cement core is pretty elaborate. Makes you wonder if the PSU manufacturer is getting ripped off by the transformer guy.

Comment: @Trevor I don't think so. Decent PSU manufacturers have QA. It's the PSU manufacturer who is ripping the customer off..

Comment: @EugeneSh. ya but isn't that a catch-22. One way or another it's not a "Decent PSU manufacturer".. LOL

Comment: @Trevor "Catch-22" - thanks for a new term :)

Comment: As you can see, the manufacturer of the 'component' might well be the same (compare the photo I included with the one from google). Only it's an improved model: No more taping. The plastic core form has the hook to hang the cable loop from!

Comment: Reminds me [this](https://www.geek.com/chips/crafty-chinese-stores-selling-128mb-flash-drives-as-500gb-hdd-1338039/) :)

Comment: @RohatKiliç Same as EugeneSh linked to above. A fast and efficient way to make sure your entire country is labeled as fak goods by your customers.

Comment: Could you tell us who is the manufacturer of this power supply is?